# Different colour when time left gets low

Tags: php, mysql, html

i have managed to be able to work out the time left for my 'auction' style site, however i am struggling to make the time_left variable turn red when it is less than 60 minutes to go.

Here is the code below that does it, at the moment the time left is just the #333 colour and doesn't turn into the #9f1717

```
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
$date3 = new DateTime($date);
$date4 = new DateTime($date_finished);
$interval_date = $date3->diff($date4);
//$time_left = $interval_date->d."d ". $interval_date->h."h ". $interval_date->i."m ";
$time_left = (($interval_date->d) ? $interval_date->d.'d ' : ''). (($interval_date->h) ? $interval_date->h.'h ' : ''). $interval_date->i.'m ';

$date_fini = date("d/m H:m", strtotime($date_finished));

if('m' < '59'  && ('d'=='' && 'H' =='')){
    $pro_order_colour = "#9f1717";
}
else{
    $pro_order_colour = "#333";
}
```

Thankyou for all and any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a bit of searching on google i tried the strpos() function to see whether there was a d or h in the time_left string, if there was not, it meant there was less than an hour left, so i could then change it to red. Here is the working code.

```
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
$date3 = new DateTime($date);
$date4 = new DateTime($date_finished);
$interval_date = $date3->diff($date4);
//$time_left = $interval_date->d."d ". $interval_date->h."h ". $interval_date->i."m ";
$time_left = (($interval_date->d) ? $interval_date->d.'d ' : ''). (($interval_date->h) ? $interval_date->h.'h ' : ''). $interval_date->i.'m ';

$date_fini = date("d/m H:m", strtotime($date_finished));
$pos = strpos($time_left, 'h');
$pos1 = strpos($time_left, 'd');
if ($pos !== false || $pos1 !== false) {
     $pro_order_colour = "#333";
} else {
     $pro_order_colour = "#9f1717";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing constants, not variables, so none of this will ever evaluate as true:

```
if('m' < '59'  && ('d'=='' && 'H' =='')){
```

should likely be something like this:

```
if($m < '59'  && ($d =='' && $H =='')){
```

Comment: Assign a value to like any variable $m = blahblah.  The code from dynamic accomplishes what you want - all the string operations are quite unnecessay to do this elapsed time calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work because 'm' is not less than a number because it's a character :)

`if('m' < '59'  && ('d'=='0' && 'H' =='0')){`

Just do this:

```
$date = mktime(time());
$date_fini = mktime(time()) + 3599;
$timeleft = intval($date_fini - $date); //assuming $date is the current time
if($timeleft < 3600) //3600 seconds in an hour
{
$pro_order_colour = "#9f1717";
} else {
$pro_order_colour = "#333";
}
```

Make sure to replace date_fini.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately everything turns red, even when the time left is 1d 14h 34m, any ideas why? Thanks for the help

Comment: @user1136379 Are you sure that $date is the current timestamp?

Comment: can you give me an example of a finish time?

Comment: `07/06 09:06` would end in red and `05/06 10:06` should end in black, the local time is `June 7, 2012, 9:38PM`

Comment: @user1136379 Fixed, was just a stupid mistake I made. Works 100%!

Comment: @user1136379 Try dumping $date, $date_fini, and $timeleft, and make extra sure that they contain the values you think they do. Also try changing _both_ possible values for $pro_order_colour so you can verify that that's actually what's setting the color of your echoed time.

Comment: ok i var dumped all listed above and they all come out fine, just out of ease of mind, is it ok to put the code you supplied underneath all of the code i supplied above, its not in place of it? Is there any chance you could just edit your code with the code i also supplied, just to make sure i am not doing anything wrong there

Comment: @user1136379 please provide the return values of var_dump then we can help :)